# Getting Error while running the jsp file.As this dynamic web project is done using strut2 spring3 hibernate4

Tags: java, struts2, classnotfoundexception, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

Actually I'm trying to implement Struts2 with Spring3 along with Hibernate4.
When i start the Apache Tomcat Server and runs the `index.jsp` file, it gives me the following error.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 05, 2013 9:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 05, 2013 9:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/hibernate_strut_spring] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 05, 2013 9:24:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 05, 2013 9:24:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 05, 2013 9:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 425 ms
```

Please help me.I'm a beginner in this topics. please help me friends.

After i added all relevant jar files within the WEB-INF/lib
it is showing some other error as below

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider;)V
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_DefaultProperties(Dispatcher.java:310)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 05, 2013 9:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 05, 2013 9:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/hibernate_strut_spring] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 05, 2013 9:46:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 05, 2013 9:46:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 05, 2013 9:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2836 ms
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>hibernate_strut_spring</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class> 
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you put all the relevant jar files under `WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes i'm using eclipse kepler

Comment: i just added all relevant jar files in libraries

Comment: You don't state which version you're using, but that's the deprecated filter dispatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Same versions of struts jar in your Project. I think u have used different versions & also u missed some jars.

Answer (score 0):

The struts jar `struts2-core-XXXX.jar` where `XXXX` denotes the version needs to find its way on to the classpath of the application.

This can be achieved by including it within `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I'm not using maven in this.

Comment: @Prasanna That will be painful.

Comment: @Prasanna What does your WEB-INF/lib directory contain?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, do `CTRL + SHIFT +T` and type FilterDispatcherand  see if you can find `struts2-core-requiredVersion.jar` in window. Most probably you will not that why you are getting thir error as .You need to add this jar under `ProjectDirectory/WEB-INF/lib`.

If you are using maven then add following dependency

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>latestVersion</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: He is not using maven